# Is $this->load->model('model_name'); == $var = new Model_name();?

Tags: php, codeigniter, oop, coding-style

I want to know if I'm doing the right thing Object Oriented Programming in Codeigniter Models because I'm confused with `$this->load->model('model_name');` and `$var = new Model_name();`

Right now I'm using `$this->load->model('model_name');` and I can call all functions using `$this->model_name->functionName();` while on the other hand, where lots of tutorials of OOP using this one `$var = new Model_name();` and I also able to call all functions using `$model_name->functionName()`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't worry. You are using it correctly and assigning it to the CI object. The vast majority of times when you see it structured

```
$model = new Model();
```

Is when models are implemented in custom libraries out of the CI instance.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually I can also do like `$this->ci =& get_instance();` and load the model with `$this->ci->load->model('model_name');`. Can you discuss it further? cause I've that feeling that I'm still doing the procedural way not the OOP way

Comment: The only time you need to get an instance of CI is when the class you in does not extend CI. When your class starts.. my controller extends CI_Controller you automatically inherit the parent classes methods hence $this is refering directly to CI. If you have an external class your loading that you would like to access CI features in you need to get an instance in order to access the CI object. Hence $this->ci. If your working in a CI model/controller rather use your inherited methods or you will pollute your scope

Comment: Sorry I forgot to say that I'm talking of what you said earlier `custom libraries`. I just want to know if `$this->load->model('model_name');` and `$var = new Model_name();` is identical? why? why not?

Comment: Yes they are,except that $this->load->model automatiocally assigns the model to a variable within the $CI class, equivelant to $this->ci->my_model = new my_model()